# Finite field implies finite number of irreducible polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question asks

> Let $k$ be a finite field. Is it true that the number of irreducible polynomials in $k[x]$ is also finite?

I believe this is not necessarily true, since we could find an irreducible polynomial for every degree. Is this idea correct?

Comment: Yes, that idea is correct (in fact, the number of irreducible polynomials is *never* finite).

Comment: Euclid's argument applies. ;)

Comment: Your initial thought is also correct, but not quite as easy to prove as showing polynomial rings are UFDs.  A lot of the related links to this question will show you how to show the existence of an irreducible polynomial in any degree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Dustan Levenstein, you can use the standard argument for infinitude of primes. Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in k[x]$ be any polynomials (of positive degree). Put $f=f_1\cdot \cdots\cdot f_n+1$. Then $f$ is not divisible by any $f_i$.